# error: undefined reference to '_jstring* QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<_jstring*>(char const*, char const*)'

Tags: android, c++, qt, linker-errors, qtandroidextras

I'm trying to use `QAndroidJniObject`. As a test I'm just calling 2 Java functions, one returns an int, the other a string.

When returning an int, this code compiles fine:

```
jint a = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<jint>("HelloJava", "getInt");
```

But if I change it to calling a function returning a string, it fails:

```
jstring b = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<jstring>("HelloJava", "getString");
```

It fails with

> error: undefined reference to '_jstring*
>   QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<_jstring*>(char const*, char
>   const*)'

Since `QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod` is a template function, how can it be defined for one type but undefined for another?

**Edit:** Actually, I just tested with `jobject`, `jbyteArray`, `jbooleanArray`, `jbyte`, `jboolean`, etc. This is what I found - only the integral number types such as `jshort`, `jint`, `jlong`, `jboolean` work, while strings, arrays, and objects all give an `undefined reference` error.

Comment: Integer types are primitive, whereas jstring is not.

Comment: So `QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod` is not supposed to work with `jstring` and `jobject`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in the [following table](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html#jni-types), the integer types are primitive, whereas the rest are object types. Therefore, I suggest that you try using instead:

```
jstring b = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod<jstring>("HelloJava", "getString")
```

This is not a bug, but a feature. See [this issue tracker entry](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-37212) on the official stance:

[QAndroidJniObject/jstring : no reference](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-37212)

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
 QAndroidJniObject jb = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("HelloJava", "getString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
 QString b = jb.toString();
```